# Including #N/A in If formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to check whether a cell is not equal to #N/A & if so include that with another cell to check both are same

Comment: Did you try anything? How far did you get? I mean a quick Google search brought up ~200 results , and there are simlar posts here already http://superuser.com/questions/476245/excel-if-statement-with-n-a/476246 ...

Comment: do you mean `=IFERROR(A1=B1,"one of the cells contains error")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNA(A1),"Do nothing", "Then do what want, such as SUM(A1+A2)")
```

I think should get you going.

A real example would be

```
=IF(ISNA(A1),"", B1+A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What Dave offered will work, using **IF**(**ISNA**(...))

However, it may be a bit shorter to employ the **IFERROR**() function. If you want to sum A1 and B1, returning an empty string if either are N/A, then use:

```
=IFERROR(A1+B1,"")
```

Or, if you want to compare values in B1 and B2, and return "same" or "not same", and handle #N/A conditions, then use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1=B2,"same","not same"),"not same due to error")
```

Comment: How is this shorter? My offering `=IF(ISNA(A1),"", B1+A1)` is shorter than `=IFERROR(IF(B1=B2, B1+A1,""),"")` by 9 characters?! It's also less convoluted as you don't have multiple "else" statements. You can make it shorter, by simply using `IFERROR(A1=B1,"")` but only by 4 characters! :)

Comment: @Dave If the objective is to simply add two cells, returning "" if either are #N/A, then it would be `IFERROR(A1+B1,"")`, which is shorter (and also has the advantage of handing #N/A in _either_ A1 or B1.